# Why do some bootstrap rows take on 1470px and other 1440px width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone explain to me why is bootstrap doing this?

All i want is for my rows to be all same width but instead some rows on the page are 1470 and others are 1440px wide, whys is this?

Both rows are in the same container...

Markup:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="header">
                <h1 class="text-center">This is the header!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"> <!-- NAVIGATION START -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="navigation">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share the basic HTML for the rows?

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen that there is a 30px difference which is occured due to 15px of right and left padding.

If you have added the class 'row' in div, it will negate the paddings(left and right) by -15px.

Comment: I do have the class .row in all of my elements. See code below

Comment: @EliTamosauskas : Please add your html markup in question itself or create a fiddle. It will be better for us to understand.

Comment: Posted code just there, should be able to see it now. In this situation my header is 15px wider on each side than the nav below it... For reasons i cannot seem to understand.

Comment: The issue is there. I added background color so you can see. Extent the viewport window and you will see it too.

Comment: No. Header and items are aligned. You added id below.  Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/L82s64kt/3/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this boys not used to interface still, you should see the code below now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="header">
                <h1 class="text-center">This is the header!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"> <!-- NAVIGATION START -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="navigation">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- NAVIGATION END -->
```